# Can you build and run models and statistical functions in Google's BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

How can you develop or use statistical functions in Google's BigQuery?   Can you run Java, PHP, R, etc on the Google platform, or does it mainly support only SQL type features?

Answer (score 1):

Google BigQuery supports a very limited set of statistical functions (avg, variance, quantiles). If you want to use R, Java, etc, you need to extract the data first. There is an open source JDBC driver that you can use from Java, or you can use the BigQuery client libraries. As for R, there have been a couple of examples of people writing an R connector to perform BigQuery queries and manipulate the results as an R data frame but I don't know any details.

Answer (score 1):

If Python is a choice, the Pandas library has a very simple connector for reading and writing into BigQuery. Look for [Pandas.read_gbq](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#io-bigquery).

Answer (score 0):

I just started using R and was also interested in connecting to BigQuery from there as well. Unfortunately the BigQuery client for R referenced [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-r-client/) has been taken down.

I did happen to find a link to the connector in the [CRAN archive](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/googlebigquery/) though I haven't started testing it yet.